# How to configure `storybook-addon-react-docgen` to NOT update args?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, storybook

When I add `storybook-addon-react-docgen` addon to storybook, it automatically updates the args that a component gets based on the type definition. It's not my desired output because I want only some specific args to be present in the controls tab. For example when I enable that in `.storybook/main.ts`:

```
typescript: {
    reactDocgen: "react-docgen-typescript",
},
```

Things like `className` show up in the controls tab and I don't want that to happen.

On the other hand, I use it to auto-generate documentation for the components and it saves me tons of time.

Is there any way to config `storybook-addon-react-docgen` to only use the type information for the docs and not the args?

I use Storybook v7.5.1, with `@storybook/nextjs` v7.5.1 and Typescript v5.2.2.